# how to print out all certian json data in database?

Tags: database, json, angle

What I'm trying is I have a page which you can input 3 angel integers and submit.
After you submit the data will be saved in database using json encode

```
{"angle1":"60","angle2":"60","angle3":"90","submit":"Submit"}
```

The above is what's saved into a row

I used

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE 'angle%' ORDER BY option_name";
$options = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
foreach ( $options as $option )
{
    echo '<p><b>'.$option->option_name.'</b> = '
         .esc_attr($option->option_value).'</p>'.PHP_EOL;

    $line = json_decode($option->option_value, true);
}
echo '<span style="color:#f00;">'.'Angel 1 : '.$line['angle1'].'</span><br>';
echo '<span style="color:#0f0;">'.'Angel 2 : '.$line['angle2'].'</span><br>';
echo '<span style="color:#00f;">'.'Angel 3 : '.$line['angle3'].'</span><br>';
```

This prints out angel 1 : ## where ## is the angle entered and so on.
I also made a simple 2d piechart which shows the angles.

the problem I'm having is if I submit another 3 angles then my result only shows the MOST RECENT angles entered even if there are two or more in the database.

For example in my database I can see

```
{"angle1":"60","angle2":"60","angle3":"90","submit":"Submit"}
{"angle1":"60","angle2":"60","angle3":"180","submit":"Submit"}
{"angle1":"30","angle2":"60","angle3":"180","submit":"Submit"}
```

but the result only prints 30 60 and 180 instead of printing all three.
Anyone mind giving me a hand on how I can print all three data out or at least all three sets of the angles.  I believe once I figured that out I can then print out all the piecharts with all the angles instead right now only the most recent angle and the piechart are printed.

Thanks a lot people~

P.S.

I'm so so so stupid I didn't put those echo into the foreach loop but my other question is I believe I need to input my codes below into the foreach loop but there are so many tags is there a way to input all those into the foreach loop instead of doing something like echo canvas id="piechart1" blah blah blah and do it bit by bit?

```
<canvas id="piechart1" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/piechart.js'; ?>"></script>
<script>
    var chartId = "piechart1";
    var colours = ["#f00", "#0f0", "#00f"];
    var angles =  [<?php echo $line['comp2052_angle1'].','.
                              $line['comp2052_angle2'].','.
                              $line['comp2052_angle3'];
                   ?>];
    piechart(chartId, colours, angles);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not print 3 results, because you put them out of `for` scope. It only print the last `$line` because `$line` will replace every `for` loops.

To fixed it.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE 'angle%' ORDER BY option_name";
$options = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
foreach ( $options as $option )
{
    echo '<p><b>'.$option->option_name.'</b> = '
         .esc_attr($option->option_value).'</p>'.PHP_EOL;

    $line = json_decode($option->option_value, true);

    // put the echo in for scope
    echo '<span style="color:#f00;">'.'Angel 1 : '.$line['angle1'].'</span><br>';
    echo '<span style="color:#0f0;">'.'Angel 2 : '.$line['angle2'].'</span><br>';
    echo '<span style="color:#00f;">'.'Angel 3 : '.$line['angle3'].'</span><br>';
    echo '<hr/>'; // to separate each data
}
```

You can stored `line` into `array` then print their when you want it. for example.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE 'angle%' ORDER BY option_name";
$options = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

// added to stored line
$line = array();
foreach ( $options as $option )
{
    echo '<p><b>'.$option->option_name.'</b> = '
         .esc_attr($option->option_value).'</p>'.PHP_EOL;

    $line[] = json_decode($option->option_value, true);
}
```

Then. You can mixed html and php in the pretty ways like code below.

```
<?php foreach($line as $i => $l): ?>
<canvas id="piechart<?php echo $i?>" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<script>
    var chartId = "piechart<?php echo $i?>";
    var colours = ["#f00", "#0f0", "#00f"];
    var angles =  [<?php echo $l['angle1'].','.
                              $l['angle2'].','.
                              $l['angle3'];
                   ?>];
    piechart(chartId, colours, angles);
</script>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Put this anywhere in html before the code above

```
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/piechart.js'; ?>"></script>
```

Comment: OMG! why am I having this simple mistake! Thanks...but there is one more thing is that the pie chart I made is using canvas and script html tags I believe I need to implement those tags into the for loop for my pie to also print out too.  How can I implement LOTS tags into php at once? I will post out my script for the canvas now.

Comment: this is awesome! ah....I never new I can put foreach loop in a line and the loop will still run until you put `<?php endforeach; ?>`to end it. thanks a lot~! learned another new thing today.

Comment: sorry to bother, but know where I can read articles about endforeach? I realized when you used the `<canvas id="piechart<?php echo $i?>" width="100" height="100"></canvas>` the $i=0 then 1 then 2 and adds on because of the for loop but when I just use `echo $i` nothing is given.  I think that's why I never thought the loop would work even after php is closed with `?>`

Comment: `$i` variable is only visible in the loop. if you access it out of the loop it will not have a value. for more info about `foreach` checkout this http://www.tizag.com/phpT/foreach.php

Comment: ok thanks.  I thought you accessed it outside the loop that's why the `piechart<?php echo $i?>` worked

Comment: I just read the link, that's regular foreach loop but then how did the `piechart<?php echo $i?>` worked outside the loop? that's what I didn't get :(

Comment: OK i understand now. the `foreach($line as $i => $l):` is define the loop is started no matter `?>` are end or not. You can see `:` behind `foreach` is means after this it will be loop scope until you put `endforeach;` to end the loop.

Comment: ah ! OMG thanks! so actually the $i and $l can be used as long as `;` is added and `endforeach` isn't used yet..OMG thanks! I didn't see this anywhere in all those foreach tutorials..thanks thanks...